# How to create new Const and push value? React

Tags: reactjs

```
onChangeCheckbox = (variant) => e => {
        const {value} = e.target;
        const {question: {currentUserAnswerVariants, currentUserAnswerComment, maxAnswersQuantity}, updateQuestion, index} = this.props;
        const answerIndex = currentUserAnswerVariants.indexOf(value);

        if (maxAnswersQuantity === 1 && answerIndex === -1) {
            while (currentUserAnswerVariants.length) {
                currentUserAnswerVariants.pop();
            }
        } else if (answerIndex > -1) {
            currentUserAnswerVariants.splice(answerIndex, 1);
        }

        if (answerIndex === -1) {
            if (this.props.questionnaireType === 50) {
                currentUserAnswerVariants.push(value);
            } else {
                currentUserAnswerVariants.push(value);
            }
```

How to get variant.text from another variable?
Now if i use `currentUserAnswerVariants.push(value, variant.text);` it's work correctly
   But i didnt need to send another value **(variant.text)** in currentUserAnswerVariants it's error for post method.
   How can i use push(variant.text); separately and next step is take variant.text value on page
   `const currentUserAnswerVariantsVariantText = question.currentUserAnswerVariants.filter(variant => ["canComment"].indexOf(variant) === -1);`
but i need to create new currentUserAnswerVariants to another variable

like

```
const answerText = currentUserAnswerVariants(variant.text);
```

and push it like `currentUserAnswerVariants.push(value);` but i always have to problem like it's not a function or undef

Answer (score 0):

CurrentUserAnswerVariantsText is not an array its value from your array see line

```
const currentUserAnswerVariantsText = currentUserAnswerVariants.indexOf(variant.text);
```

If you want to change it then you need to declare it as var instead of const.

Comment: How to push this currentUserAnswerVariantsText to page from component ?
like  currentUserAnswerVariants.push(value); 
When i use push it say this is doent function! 
And when i console.log(currentUserAnswerVariantsText); = -1 but i take value 2

Comment: That means variant.text is not present in the currentUserAnswerVariants array.

Comment: Where you want to push it?

Comment: I have page.js (and component question.js where is i need to do push to page) for create new const on page like (`const currentUserAnswerVariantsVariantIds = question.currentUserAnswerVariants.filter(variant => ["canComment"].indexOf(variant) === -1);`)

Comment: `var answerText = variant.text;
  console.log(value);console.log(answerText);
  if (answerIndex === -1) {
   if (this.props.questionnaireType === 50) {
    currentUserAnswerVariants.push(value);
    answerText.push(variant.text);
   } else {
    currentUserAnswerVariants.push(value);
   }` how to push it?